# Ternary operator in Swift Error

Tags: swift

Why does this code gives error(Swift 2.2) :

> Expected Expresion

at return line

```
func == (lhs: Employee, rhs: Employee) -> Int {
    return (lhs.empName == rhs.empName && lhs.empCode == rhs.empCode)?1:0
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly. There has to be a space between the `BOOL` being checked upon and the `?`

So `flag?expressionA:expressionB` won't work.
Instead `flag ?expressionA:expressionB` will work.

Maybe compiler assumes `flag?` as optional chaining.

This works

```
func == (lhs: Employee, rhs: Employee) -> Int {
    return (lhs.empName == rhs.empName && lhs.empCode == rhs.empCode) ?1:0
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to use the ternary operator here — `x ? true : false` is exactly the same as `x`. I'd write:

```
func ==(lhs: Employee, rhs: Employee) -> Bool {
    return lhs.empName == rhs.empName && lhs.empCode == rhs.empCode
}
```